# jQuery: Add Class to P inside an li - whenhover over that specific li?

Tags: jquery

I have multile li tags (Around 24) - and within them, is an image, and a p tag...

My quetion is...

If I hover over the li e.g. the li itself, the image within or the p...how can I add a class to the p tag?

```
<li>
<img src="" alt="" />
<p>sometexthere</p>
```

and then when I hover over any of those elements of that li, the p get's a class added to it e.g.

```
<li>
<img src="" alt="" />
<p class="newclass">sometexthere</p>
```

Note: That it can only be applied to the current li's p not make the change to all the p's within all 24 li's... - Just the current hovered block.

Basically i'm looking just to change the background of the p...so a bonus would to be able to switch class, but with a fade effect (If possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').hover(function() {
  $('p', this).toggleClass('new-class');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch a class with effect.

This is jQuery example to add and remove class on :hover

```
$('ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('p').addClass('newclass');
},function(){
    $(this).find('p').removeClass('newclass');
})
```

Comment: Thank you, any idea how to add a fade effect with this switch please? - so it gently fades to the new bg colour?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to change the bg color with straight css

```
li:hover p {
  background-color:red;
}
```